# mysql not getting installed

Tags: server, apt, mysql

I installed mysql with the following command sudo apt-get install mysql-server and it got installed correclty.then i uninstalled it by refering this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853004/removing-mysql-5-5-completely

first answer,

then tried install 5.0.96 fro their official site doenloading the rpm, converting to deb, and installing it, it failed, again i purged everything rebooted and tried to install with the same old command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

but every thing will go correclty till this place and will get stuck i waited for about an hour,

this is the terminal log

```
mukund@mukund-ThinkPad-Edge-E431:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
libdbd-mysql-perl libmysqlclient18 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5
 mysql-common mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
Suggested packages:
 tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 libdbd-mysql-perl libmysqlclient18 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5
 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
 0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
 Need to get 0 B/8,351 kB of archives.
 After this operation, 94.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
 Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 235747 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmysqlclient18:amd64.
Preparing to unpack    .../libmysqlclient18_5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdbd-mysql-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libdbd-mysql-perl_4.025-1_amd64.deb ...
 Unpacking libdbd-mysql-perl (4.025-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-5.5.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-   core-5.5_5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.5 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.5.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client- 5.5_5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.5.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.5 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.5.




(Reading database ... 235938 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server- 5.5_5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.025-1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.5 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.5 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
160407 14:27:27 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160407 14:27:27 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.  Please use the full name instead.
160407 14:27:27 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log) starting as process 2327 ...
```

and said an error message about password, says that user already exists i clicked ok, then nothing.......

please help me in this matter

this is the mysql/error.log

```
160408 15:05:46 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160408 15:05:46 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
160408 15:05:46 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
160408 15:05:46 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160408 15:05:46 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160408 15:05:46 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160408 15:05:46 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160408 15:05:46 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160408 15:05:46 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160408 15:05:46 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160408 15:05:46  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160408 15:05:47 InnoDB: 5.5.47 started; log sequence number 1595675
160408 15:05:47 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--skip-locking'
160408 15:05:47 [ERROR] Aborting

160408 15:05:47  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
```

Comment: Is it already running? Find out with `sudo service mysql status`. If it isn't running, find out why in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`.

Comment: this is what i get `mysql start/post-start, process 8756
 post-start process 8757
` and when i try to start it via `mysql -u root -p` i am getting this  ` Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: So, anything in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`?

Comment: i posted it in question itself

Comment: Try removing `/etc/my.cnf` and restarting mysql. Then run `mysql_upgrade -u <user> -p`.

Comment: tried but `Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Error: Failed while fetching Server version! Could be due to unauthorized access.`
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed

Comment: OK, but now the server is running. Try `mysql_upgrade -u root -p`, as suggested by [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/527422/mysql-upgrade-is-failing-with-no-real-reason-given).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server
sudo apt-get autoremove
less /etc/passwd
```

Check right at the bottom if there is a mysql user. If there is:

```
sudo userdel mysql
```

After all this is done, try to install Mysql again using the command  you used previously.

Comment: it almost worked, when i tried `mysql -u root -p` it throws an error  `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` and on googling i ran it like this 'mysql -u root' then it worked. is there any problem in running like this?

Comment: No, I run mine like that as well. However be careful to enter the password in the clear.  I usually use `mysql -u root -p` and will then be prompted for  a password. Also I would suggest adding a password for the mysql root user. Another google search should show how to do this quite quickly

Answer (score 0):

`Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

the error occur when mysql service not start.

no need to remove mysql.

please follow mentioned below steps:
 $ sudo su

/etc/init.d/mysql start